# how can i decode a String for html text box if the string is coming from javascript with encoding

Tags: javascript, jsp

we are working on a project that uses struts 2 ,JSP and for validations we are using JavaScript coming to my problem , in some cases we are setting text box values from JavaScript   on page on Load() method . in that we are encoding string in order to avoid script errors and next we are setting that value to text box . but I want to decode that text box value before its setting to text box and then after decoding it we need to display in text box . thanks in advance.
              and the code is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">








<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojox/widget/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojox/form/resources/FileInput.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"  djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: false" src="/cxp/scripts/dojo 1.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/cxp/scripts/jquery/libs/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/cxp/scripts/jquery/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cxp/scripts/jquery/libs/date.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/cxp/scripts/jquery/jquery.weekcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/cxp/scripts/jquery/jquery-dateformat.js'></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/cxp/scripts/jquery/libs/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/styles.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/wareHouseStyles.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/maintenance.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/dojostyles.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/supervisor.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/warehouse.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cxp/styles/alignment.css"></link>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/js/popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/js/date.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/js/validations.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/js/dojovalidations.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/js/reports.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/js/formateDate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/cxp/scripts/jspspellcheck/spellcheck-caller.js"></script>
</head>
<head>
<title>CaterXpert - Maintenance</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.RadioButton");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
     var res;
    dojo.addOnLoad (function() { 
         var id="54";
        /*  var id1="lookupBean [Type=""#***^&&&'''#$^%''&$#@"L:"?>aa, lookupId=54, Status=null, SortOrder=1, Active=1, Days=null, category=null, name=null, unitTypeId=null, invSupplierId=null, beverageCategoryID=null, cost=null, price=null, description=null, unitId=null, caterDocsId=null, sOrder=0, lookUpActive=null, taxType=null]"; */
         if(id >0 && id !=""){

                                dojo.byId("Type1").value=decodeTags("&#034;&#034;#***^&amp;&amp;&amp;&#039;&#039;&#039;#$^%&#039;&#039;&amp;$#@&#034;L:&#034;?&gt;aa‌​");

                               dojo.byId("SortOrder2").value="1";
                }
         if(id > 0 && id !=""){
            var active  =   '1';
            if(active ==1){
                dijit.byId("active").setValue(true);
            }
            else if(status ==0){
                dijit.byId("inactive").setValue(true);
            }
         }
          if (document.pub) {
              document.pub();
          } 

       });  

    function decodeTags(str) {
        return str
             .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
             .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
             .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
             .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
             .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
             // add whatever you want to replace.
     }
      function submitForm(){
       if(validateAll()){
           var type =  dojo.byId("type").value;

                 document.getElementById("lookupId").value=1;

           document.forms[0].action = "saveSystemSettingLookup.action?type="+type;
           document.forms[0].submit();
        }
     }

      function validateAll(){ 
         var temp=true;


                            if(dojo.byId("Type1").value==""){
                            alert("Empty Type");
                            temp=false;
                              }
                            if(res>0){
                                alert('DUPLICATE TYPE TRY AGAIN');
                                temp=false;
                            }


                   var sortOrder= dojo.byId("SortOrder2").value;
                   if(sortOrder !=""){
                      var onlyNums = /[^0-9]/g;
                               if (onlyNums.test(sortOrder)) { 
                                   alert(" Invalid Sort Order"); 
                                  temp= false;
                                }
                      }



            return temp;
     }

    function doClose()
    {
         var lookUpId  =  dojo.byId("id").value;
         var type  =  dojo.byId("type").value;
           if(lookUpId > 0){
               parent.view.location.replace("/cxp/corpmaintenance/viewSystemSettingLookup.action?type="+type);

            }
            else{
                 window.parent.location="/cxp/corpmaintenance/viewCorpMaintenanceFrame.action";
         }
    }

    function duplicateChecking()
    {
        res = 0;
         var type = dojo.byId("type").value;
         var id   = document.getElementById("id").value;
         var columnName=document.getElementById("columnName").value;
         var idValue1=document.getElementById("idValue").value;
         var name = document.getElementById(idValue1).value;
         /* This code is for Ajax*/
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
          {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        else
          {
          alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
              {
                res = eval( "("+ xmlhttp.responseText +")" );
                submitForm();

              }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/cxp/corpmaintenance/checkSystemSettingLookup.action?columnName="+columnName+"&name="+name+"&type="+type+"&id="+id+"&rand="+Math.random(),true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    } 

</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div>
<form  name="bean" action="" id="bean">
  <input  name="id"  id="id" type="hidden" value="54" />
  <input  name="type" id="type" type="hidden" value="DeliveryType" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lookupId"  id ="lookupId"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="formName" id="formName" value=""></input>

            <table class="formContentPane column-width35" align="center">
             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

                    <tr>  
                                    <td class="paddingleftfive" style="width: 5%" nowrap="nowrap"><label>Type</label></td>
                                    <td class="mandatoryField" style="width: 3px">
                                    </td>

                        <td >       
                                            <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox"  id="Type1"  name="bean.Type" size="0" maxlength="50"/>

                                        <input type="hidden" id="columnName" name="columnName" value="Type"></input>
                                            <input type="hidden" id="idValue" name="idValue" value="Type1"></input>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>  
                                    <td class="paddingleftfive" style="width: 5%" nowrap="nowrap"><label>SortOrder</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>


                        <td >    
                                        <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox"  id="SortOrder2"  
                                        name="bean.SortOrder" size="0" maxlength="5"/>


                                        <input type="hidden" id="columnName" name="columnName" value="SortOrder"></input>
                                            <input type="hidden" id="idValue" name="idValue" value="SortOrder2"></input>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 5%" nowrap="nowrap" class="paddingleftfive"><label>Active</label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <input  dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" checked="checked" id="active" name="bean.active" type="radio" value="1"/>
                            <label>Yes</label>
                            <input  dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" name="bean.active" id="inactive" type="radio" value="0"/>
                            <label>No</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>

             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
       </table>

            <table class="saveclosebuttons" align="center" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">

                                <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="duplicateChecking()" class="mediumbutton" type="button">
                                Save</button>

                            <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="doClose()" class="mediumbutton" type="button">
                            Close</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the decode you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thank you for your response like < ,> ," ,' ,& ,* these special characters I need to decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to convert < to & lt; or vise versa, but you can write a function in javascript to decode all the unwanted characters.

```
function decodeTags(str) {
    return str
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
         // add whatever you want to replace.
 }
```

Editing my original answer. Thanks for all the details and the detailed html code. It looks like we need to do the reverse of what we did.

```
function decodeTags(str) {
    return str
         .replace(/&#034;/g, "\"")
         .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
         .replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
         .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
         .replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
         // add whatever you want to replace.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but actually I don't have any idea when to call this function and set these values .the following code we are using. and on load code is:dojo.addOnLoad (function() { 
   <c:forEach items="${metaLookupDetailsList}" var="metaLookupDetails" varStatus="status">
     <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${metaLookupDetails.name=='Type'}">
        dojo.byId("Type${status.count}").value="${fn:escapeXml(lookupBean.type)}";
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
      </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
       
   </c:forEach> 
  }

Comment: Try adding it here dojo.byId("Type${status.count}").value= decodeTags("${fn:escapeXml(lookupBean.type)}‌​"); and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have this string: !@#$@%^$*&()}":":"  and its displaying like !@#$@%^$*&amp;amp;()}&amp;#034;:&amp;#034;:&amp;#034;â€Œâ€‹ and code is ::<c:when test="${metaLookupDetails.name=='Type'}">
        dojo.byId("Type${status.count}").value=decodeTags("${fn:escapeXml(lookupBean.type)}‌​");
      </c:when>

Comment: OK, is that the thing you expected to display? If not, can you please tell me the expected string to display?

Comment: no didn't get any solution. is there any option here to add txt files if possible I will show you my complete code.

Comment: i had added my code to above question hope it will helpful to you for finding the solution.

Comment: Can you please paste the html and not the server pages. You can view source of the page in a browser and paste it here.

Comment: Thanks for pasting the html. As you can see the id is coming as null or "", which means the if statement if(id >0 && id !="") is never satisfied. You have to check your server side on why id is coming as null.

Comment: Thanks for pasting the html. As you can see the id is coming as null or "", which means the if statement if(id >0 && id !="") is never satisfied. You have to check your server side on why id is coming as null.

Comment: now you can check the code thank you for your response.

Comment: this is not decoding still its displaying encoded value only

Answer (score 0):

You can do encoding and decoding  like this :

```
function encode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function decode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```